# bash function to "wrap" 7z

Tags: bash

[It appears that 7z can't write to a pipe](https://sourceforge.net/p/p7zip/discussion/383044/thread/8066736d/), so I wrote the following bash function to emulate this functionality.

I know this is a simple problem, but this is my first bash function and I feel like it's really easy to write faulty code in bash, so any feedback is appreciated.

```
function 7z2pipe () (
    local out_dir=$(mktemp -d)
    local out_file="${out_dir}"/temp.7z
    local log_file="${out_dir}"/"outz.txt"

    7z -p"weak_password" -mhe=on a "${out_file}" "$@" &> "${log_file}"
   
    if [ $? -ne 0  ]; then
        cat "${log_file}"
        return $?
    fi

    cat "${out_file}"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Do you want to make persistent temporary files?

Note that while the default settings for `mktemp` put things in /tmp so that it will eventually get garbage collected, it doesn't immediately get garbage collected.  Things can persist in /tmp for days.

#### `cat` has a return code

I'm not sure why are returning the return code from `cat`.  Wouldn't it make more sense to return the return code from `7z`?

#### Alternative code

```
    local return_code=$?
    if [ ${return_code} -ne 0]; then
        cat "${log_file}"
    else
        cat "${out_file}"
    fi

    rm -rf ${out_dir}
    return ${return_code}
```

That will leave things as you found them, with no extra temporary directories or files.

It will always return the return code from `7z`.

It will output either the log file or the output file, as you originally did it.

#### Redirect to `stderr`

I'm not sure that your approach is what I would do.  An alternative to creating the log file would be to redirect `stdout` to `stderr`.

```
    local out_file=$(mktemp --suffix .7z)
    7z -p"weak_password" -mhe=on a "${out_file}" "$@" 1>&2

    local return_code=$?

    cat "${out_file}"
    rm -f ${out_file}

    return ${return_code}
```

Now `stdout` will contain the compressed file and `stderr` will have all the output from the command.

Note:  I do not normally use Bash functions, so don't take anything I say as validation of function syntax.

Comment: Actually, `mktemp` will put its file into `$TMPDIR` if that's set (this is how `pam_tmpdir` implements per-user temporary directories).  The point still stands that it's good practice to add a `trap` to clean up, of course.